# HTML can't properly read unicode in image tag src

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, filenames

I am using electron with html, css and js. For my desktop app, I want to import an image from my local storage using an img tag. However, my file name contains an unicode (e.g. #). When, HTML try to fetch the image it gets rid of the second half part of the file name starting from the unicode.See the example below please.

```
<img src= "path/to/my/example#file.png">
```

This becomes, src= "path/to/my/example"

by deleting the part after the Unicode.
Returning me ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in console.

using %23 may be an option however,
The filename is unfortunately unpredictable and it changes based on the file (I import several pictures). So, obtaining the filename and creating the HTML tag is automized using javascript. Is there a way for the javascirpt to automatically catch unicode in a string (path to file) and enforce it so that html can read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is not a "unicode" as you call it.  It is just a plain ASCII character.  But, within a url, it just happens to be a *reserved* character, used to denote an anchor within a resource, and so is not part of the resource's path, which is why you see it getting stripped off.

So, you must url-encode (ie, percent-encode) the `#` character as `%23` if it is meant to be used inside the path itself, eg:

```html
<img src="path/to/my/example%23file.png">
```

Since you said that you need to generate this HTML via JavaScript, you will need to have your script parse the file path and encode any reserved characters as needed.  In fact, JavaScript has built-in functions for this exact purpose: `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! when I convert the entire file path with encodeURIComponent(), it gives my an error but creating a variable inside my file path and only encoding the filename worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to 'url encode' also known as 'percent encode' all special characters. In your example, replace the `#` with `%23`.

You also incorrectly used `:` instead of `=` in the attribute:

```
<img src="path/to/my/example#file.png">
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, the filename is unfortunately unpredictable and it changes based on the file (I import several pictures). So, obtaining the filename and creating the HTML tag is automized using javascript. Is there a way for the javascirpt to automatically catch unicode and change it so that html can read it?

Comment: @ome This answer is fine for the question you asked, but you have now moved the goal posts. The additional information you provided in your comment above is highly relevant for the problem you are trying to resolve, so please update your question and add a [javascript] tag,  or it may be closed. Also show your existing JavaScript code if that is relevant.

Comment: @ome like i said, you percent / urlencode it. Easy to google